# Stop Firebug from displaying console output from a single file

Tags: javascript, firebug, console.log

I have a page with a couple of scripts it's using:

```
<script src="thirdparty.com/js/foo.js"></script>
<script src="bar.js"></script>
```

I need to use `console.log()` to print some things in bar.js, but the output keeps getting buried in all of the stuff foo.js prints to the screen which I don't care about. I don't have access to foo.js to make changes to it and removing it is out of the question.

How can I make Firebug stop console printing from foo.js and continue to allow printing from bar.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Including foo.js try to execute the following JS:

```
var _console = window.console;

window.console = {
  log: function() {},
  dir: function() {},
  .....
}
```

In this case you will have empty functions for foo.js.

In bar.js you can use **_console**.

If this is acceptable solution for you, you can think on its improvement.

Comment: That's a nice trick, though only covers messages explicitly logged via the [Console API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API), errors and warnings are not covered by that.

Answer (score 1):

"don't have access to foo.js". If that file is a released file, then say to that developer that having debug statements on released files is a big no no.

Currently, you cannot filter messages from files in Firebug. See [issue 2955](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2955). (For the Firefox built-in DevTools see [bug 905978](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=905978)) But, you can use [`console.clear()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.clear) statement at the first line of your JavaScript file to clear the console messages from the previously loaded script files.

However this does not guarantee to prevent other messages coming from other files if they have event handlers or functions with AJAX.

PS: Perhaps you have mixed foo.js with bar.js in your post. Your coding block says that bar.js is from third party while you're talking about foo.js being the culprit.

Comment: Regarding "don't have access to foo.js": The messages coming from foo.js may not be debug statements but errors or warnings. If it's a third-party library, you may really not have access to that file and the only chance to get rid of such messages is to file a bug report against that library.

Answer (score 0):

How about `console.clear()` function in bar.js before your `console.log()` calls?

Comment: That may work, though also causes all other messages logged to the console (e.g. JavaScript or CSS errors) to be removed, which is probably not expected. Also not all messages coming from foo.js will be removed by that as it may still create logs later when functions of foo.js are called.

Comment: You're right. But if he needs to do that just for debug purposes is a simple way. I like the solution of Max, it is better than mine of course. :)